# Teradata:Get a specific part of a large variable text field

Tags: parsing, teradata

My first Post: (be kind )
PROBLEM: I need to extract the View Name from a Text field that contains a full SQL Statements so I can link the field a different data source. There are two text strings that always exist on both sides of the target view. I was hoping to use these as identifying "anchors" along with a substring to bring in the View Name text from between them.
EXAMPLE:

```
from v_mktg_dm.**VIEWNAME** as lead_sql
```

(UPPER CASE/BOLD is what I want to extract)
I tried using

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(SQL_FIELD,INSTR(SQL_FIELD,'FROM V_MKTG_TRM_DM.',19),20) AS PARSED_FIELD
FROM DATABASE.SQL_STORAGE_DATA
```

But am not getting good results - 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What are those *anchors*?

Comment: "from v_mktg_dm." on the front end and " as lead_sql" after it

Comment: View name will be in between those two always

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a Regular Expression:

```
RegExp_Substr_gpl(SQL_FIELD, '(v_mktg_dm\.)(.*?)( AS lead_sql)',1,1,'i',2)
```

This looks for the string between 'v_mktg_dm.' and ' AS lead_sql'.

`RegExp_Substr_gpl` is an undocumented variation of `RegExp_Substr` which simplifies the syntax for ignoring parts of the match

Comment: looks like I one more question, there are a few variances on the SQL in that field. Is there a way to identify the second "anchor" to be a carriage return? I tried placing CHAR(13) in the field but it isn't recognized

Comment: Instead of a specific linebreak you can use a wildcard `\s` for any kind of whitespace: `RegExp_Substr_gpl(SQL_FIELD, '(v_mktg_dm\.)(.*?)(\sAS lead_sql)',1,1,'i',2)`